# apache spark start-slave throws akka.actor.ActorNotFound Exception

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to install a standalone spark cluster. I prepared 3 virtual machines each with Ubuntu installed.

The three machines consists a cluster with one master and two slaves.

I followed the steps in the documentation of Apache spark. I started the master script from the master node and it worked fine.

The problem happens with the slaves.

I tried to start the slave once using the `sbin/start-slave.sh` from each machine and another time using `sbin/start-slaves.sh` from the master node.

The workers on the slaves nodes fails to start and throws the following exception

```
15/11/06 02:12:36 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master rethink-node01:7077
akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://sparkMaster@rethink-node01:7077/), Path(/user/Master)]
        at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:65)
        at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:63)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:73)
        at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:74)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:120)
        at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.execute(Future.scala:73)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:266)
        at akka.actor.EmptyLocalActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:533)
        at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:569)
        at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.$bang(ActorRef.scala:559)
        at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef.$bang(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:87)
        at akka.remote.EndpointWriter.postStop(Endpoint.scala:557)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPostStop(Actor.scala:477)
        at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundPostStop(Endpoint.scala:411)
        at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.akka$actor$dungeon$FaultHandling$$finishTerminate(FaultHandling.scala:210)
        at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.terminate(FaultHandling.scala:172)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.terminate(ActorCell.scala:369)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:462)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: curious if the answer worked? You haven't accepted it so I assume not? How was this resolved? I think there are a couple hostname/Spark related bugs that affect this, for example https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11570

Comment: and BTW seeing what is happening in the master logs is very helpful in these situations, while the worker appears to be groping in the dark, the masters can reveal a failed connection because the master can hear the worker but can't communicate back to it. Just an idea.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this while setting up a standalone spark cluster. To me this was caused due to pure network setup issue.

From the slave machine try to do

> telnet MASTER_IP 7077

If a connection is not established then you need to either check the firewall settings or in my case check where the spark port 7077 is listening to. While it was not working, this was the output of my netstat.

> ## netstat -an | grep 7077
>
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:7077          :::*                    LISTEN

I removed my problematic entry for 127.0.0.2 from /etc/hosts and then everything started working fine.

> ## netstat -an | grep 7077
>
> tcp        0      0 1.1.1.1:7077     :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: +1 on this, It seems that Spark does not always play well with these uses of loopback address, especially other than 127.0.0.1, try searching on 127.0.1.1 and a lot of links to debian docs come up. http://serverfault.com/questions/363095/why-does-my-hostname-appear-with-the-address-127-0-1-1-rather-than-127-0-0-1-in I have to use explicit ip addresses in all my Spark configs or I get an error